# Non-threadsafe AtomicIncrement

Tags: delphi

Is there a standard function that resembles `AtomicIncrement` but not thread safe? `AtomicIncrement` both increases parameter and returns it as a new value. `Inc` is a procedure, `Succ` doesn't change parameter value.
Actually I was using the `AtomicIncrement` in the old code when there was no nice looking way of handling open arrays. So the question has almost no meaning now. Here is the example:

```
type
  TA = record
    s: string;
    constructor Create(const sparam: string);
  end;

constructor TA.Create(const sparam: string);
begin
  s := sparam;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TArray<TA>;
  i: integer;
begin
  // ancient approach
  SetLength(a, 100);
  i := -1;
  a[AtomicIncrement(i)] := TA.Create('h');
  a[AtomicIncrement(i)] := TA.Create('e');
  a[AtomicIncrement(i)] := TA.Create('l');
  a[AtomicIncrement(i)] := TA.Create('l');
  a[AtomicIncrement(i)] := TA.Create('o');
  SetLength(a, AtomicIncrement(i));

  // modern approach
  a := [];
  a := a + [TA.Create('h')];
  a := a + [TA.Create('e')];
  a := a + [TA.Create('l')];
  a := a + [TA.Create('l')];
  a := a + [TA.Create('o')];
end;
```

Comment: You are looking for C++ or `function Incr(var A: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Inc(A);
  Result := A;
end;`

Comment: Such a function is essentially useless. So write anything you like.

Comment: Yes, it's just theoretical interest

Comment: You will kick yourself when you learn about `TArray<TA>.Create`

Comment: The "modern" approach is very bad and not modern at all. In fact, it is much more inefficient than the old one. But, as David notes, you should write `a := TArray<TA>.Create(TA.Create('h'), TA.Create('e'), ...)`.

Comment: @Andreas It is not that bad, Delphi allocates memory for a bunch of array members at once. The code with TArray<>.Create is hardly readable with a lot of records and record members after code formatting.

Comment: @Molochnik: I never use automatic code formatting, so I would write one element per line even with the `Create` approach.

Comment: I use it a lot, one my favorite features

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
{$IF DEFINED(CPUARM) OR DEFINED(LINUX) }
FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int8) : Int8; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(I);
    Result:=I
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR B : UInt8) : UInt8; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(B);
    Result:=B
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int16) : Int16; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(I);
    Result:=I
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR W : UInt16) : UInt16; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(W);
    Result:=W
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int32) : Int32; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(I);
    Result:=I
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR W : UInt32) : UInt32; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(W);
    Result:=W
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int64) : Int64; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(I);
    Result:=I
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR L : UInt64) : UInt64; OVERLOAD;
  BEGIN
    INC(L);
    Result:=L
  END;
{$ELSEIF DEFINED (CPUX64) }
FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int8) : Int8; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     BYTE PTR [RCX]
                MOV     AL,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR B : UInt8) : UInt8; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     BYTE PTR [RCX]
                MOV     AL,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int16) : Int16; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     WORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     AX,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR W : UInt16) : UInt16; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     WORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     AX,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int32) : Int32; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     DWORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     EAX,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR L : UInt32) : UInt32; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     DWORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     EAX,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int64) : Int64; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     QWORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     RAX,[RCX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR L : UInt64) : UInt64; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                .NOFRAME
                INC     QWORD PTR [RCX]
                MOV     RAX,[RCX]
  END;
{$ELSE }
FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int8) : Int8; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     BYTE PTR [EAX]
                MOV     AL,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR B : UInt8) : UInt8; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     BYTE PTR [EAX]
                MOV     AL,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int16) : Int16; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     WORD PTR [EAX]
                MOV     AX,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR W : UInt16) : UInt16; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     WORD PTR [EAX]
                MOV     AX,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int32) : Int32; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     DWORD PTR [EAX]
                MOV     EAX,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR W : UInt32) : UInt32; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                INC     DWORD PTR [EAX]
                MOV     EAX,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR I : Int64) : Int64; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                XOR     EDX,EDX
                INC     EDX
                ADD     [EAX],EDX
                DEC     EDX
                ADC     [EAX+4],EDX
                MOV     EDX,[EAX+4]
                MOV     EAX,[EAX]
  END;

FUNCTION PreInc(VAR L : UInt64) : UInt64; OVERLOAD; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                XOR     EDX,EDX
                INC     EDX
                ADD     [EAX],EDX
                DEC     EDX
                ADC     [EAX+4],EDX
                MOV     EDX,[EAX+4]
                MOV     EAX,[EAX]
  END;
{$ENDIF }
```

This implements a PreInc (C's --X operator) in Delphi, optimized in assembly for Intel processors. Implementing PostInc (X++), PreAdd (X+=Y) and PostAdd is left up to the user :-)

Comment: Thanks, though it is not compiled under Linux

Comment: @Molochnik: What do you mean? The above code should work on all targets that Delphi supports.

Comment: I have just checked Delphi - Alexandria, target - Linux 64, problems with asm

Comment: @Molochnik: You didn't mention anything about Linux :-). I don't have Linux support installed, but I don't see why the above shouldn't work. Where do you get an error? And what is the error message?

Comment: @Molochnik: The only thing I can think of is that LINUX target doesn't allow inline assmbler. Can't fathom why, but I have forced the code to use the PASCAL implementation if targeting LINUX - does that solve the problem?

Comment: Looks like it. Assembler code gives the compiler error:
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(82): E1025 Unsupported language feature: 'ASM'